# Nodejs cannot find R for r-integration package [Ubuntu]

Tags: r, node.js, ubuntu

I have installed `r-integration` via npm. I have placed my R script inside the `node-server` directory which is located at `srv/nodeserver/`. I have R installed in my machine.

```
> whereis R
R: /usr/bin/R /usr/lib/R /etc/R /usr/local/lib/R /usr/share/R /usr/share/man/man1/R.1.gz
```

The nodejs REST API code looks like below:

```
app.get('/getRresult',(req,res)=>{
        let result = R.executeRScript(
                   'server.R',"circumference",{r:2});
        console.log(result)
});
```

When I hit the RESTAPI url I get the following error:

```
Error: R not found, maybe not installed.
```

However R is installed because if I type `R` in the terminal R shell opens up. I tried exporting the path of `usr/bin/R` in `~/.bashrc`. It still does not seem to work. I am confused which path will actually work or how to set the path for ubuntu PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

You needs to install R on your `ubuntu`.

Here are steps

#### #1 Install the dependencies necessary

to add a new repository over HTTPS:

```
$ sudo apt install dirmngr gnupg apt-transport-https ca-certificates software-properties-common
```

#### #2 Add the CRAN repository to your system sources’ list

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
$ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/'
```

#### #3 Install R

```
$ sudo apt install r-base
```

#### #4 Verify R version

```
R --version
```

Terminal Output

```
$ R --version
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) -- "Holding the Windsock"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
https://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
```

#### #5 Finally run simple example

`test.js` will call `test.R` by R.executeRScript()
It will return value into `test.js` then it will console.log()

file name save as `test.js`

```
const R = require('r-integration');

let result = R.executeRScript("./test.R");
console.log(result);
```

file name save as `test.R`

```
x <- 5
y <- 6
z <- 3
result <- max(x, y, z)

print(result)
```

Install `r-integration` library

```
npm install r-integration
```

Run it and see the Result

```
$ node test.js
[ 6 ]
```

References

[R-integration - Node JS API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/r-integration)

[How to Install R on Ubuntu 20.04](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-20-04/)